# Is there a simple way for to check if method was not called when a variable is undefined?

Tags: jasmine

So I have a simple method that executes something only if the passed variable is defined:

```
public myFunction(item) {
    if (typeof item !== 'undefined') {
        item.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Here's my test in jasmine:

```
    describe('myFunction()', () => {
    it ('should only do something if the item passed is defined.', () => {
        const item = new Item();
        spyOn(item, 'doSomething');
        service.myFunction(item);

        //this works   
        expect(item.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });

    it ('should not do something if the item passed is undefined.', () => {
        const item = undefined;
        spyOn(item, 'doSomething');
        service.myFunction(item);

        //this does not work.. 
        expect(item.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
    });
   });
```

My first test works fine. But I do not know how to express my second test. How can I say that `doSomething` was never called when the item passed is undefined? It seems quite trivial, but I'm having trouble with this. I have a feeling it's not possible, because I can't spy on something that is `undefined`. Then again, maybe there is a work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
it ('should not do something if the item passed is undefined.', () => {
        const item = undefined;
        const conditionForIf = typeof item !== 'undefined';
        // check the conditionForIf, if it is false, it won't go on and `doSomething`
        expect(conditionForIf).toBe(false);
    });
```

Comment: I got this error when I tried that. `Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for doSomething`

Comment: Yes, I suspected that happening. I have made an edit to test it a different way. To test it your proposed way is difficult if not impossible.